# How do IR sensors detect color?

Tags: arduino, infrared, robotics

I'm trying to make a line following robot using Arduino. I have searched the Internet for information on how to build it, but a few questions remain:

1. How does an IR sensor detect colors?
2. What voltage range do those sensors output when detecting these colors (especially black and white)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of sensors used for line following robots (IR proximity sensors) don't sense *color* in the normal use of that word. They actually sense *reflectivity*, and in particular they sense the reflectivity of whatever is right in front of them at the IR wavelength of the sensor and emitter. (Strictly speaking, the reflectivity of an object at a particular wavelength is what gives it color, I know.)

So, your sensor would work best if you had a background that absorbed IR light and a line that reflected IR light. As it turns out, the colors that we call dark colors are pretty good at absorbing near IR as well as the visible spectrum, and the colors that we call bright colors are pretty good at reflecting near IR. If you really wanted a good contrast you could use a reflective material like aluminum foil for the line and have a deep dark void surrounding the line (maybe it's a line-following blimp). You don't normally think of metal foil or empty space as having a "color", but the IR sensor can easily tell the difference.

Comment: and what about the voltage that gives if it 'detect' black or white color ?

Comment: The sensor is usually just a phototransistor so it requires a pullup resistor. The current flowing in the pullup depends on the reflectivity of the surface. You select the appropriate resistor that gives your desired voltages for your desired "black" and "white" colors. High reflectivity surfaces will always cause more current, so if you use a pullup resistor you get a lower voltage.

Comment: so i can conclude , if i use pulldown resistor , then the black color will give a lower voltage (on pulldown resistor) , and white color will give a higher voltage , also if we use a very high resistor , i will get higher sensitivity

Comment: Yes, a higher resistor value gives higher sensitivity but you may have trouble finding appropriate colors to use with it. You would need a very good absorber for the dark color.

Comment: you mean that the surface must be very good absorber for the dark color , to prevent reflection of light from it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by a good absorber.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12178/discussion-between-hassan-and-joe-hass)